# is there a utility similar to dropbox/google drive that you can choose multiple folders?

Tags: dropbox, google-drive, online-storage, pcloud

All Dropbox competitors I've tried have the same problem, they only sync one main local folder (all other folders must be inside), is there any utility that you can choose multiple folders on OS to sync?

Comment: Mega allows additional folders

Comment: I use pCloud to sync some folders between my laptop and working good. You can chose different folders in different position. Have you tried?

Comment: I found Mega and it worked, but with little options, maybe pCloud is better, I'll try it.